# Splitting Express Js start up file into modules

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

This may sound stupid, but I have been trying to split my ExpressJS start up file into modules with no success.

Here is what I would like to achieve, but when I launch the server I have no response at the request of the home address and I can't seem to find the reason.

----app.js----

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // parse json and form post

const indexRoutes = require('./Routes/index');

const app = express();


//ejs view
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');

//set cors
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET", "POST");
});

//middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//routes - MVC
app.use(indexRoutes);

module.exports = app;
```

----server.js------

```
const app = require('./app');
const http = require('http')

http.createServer(app).listen(3000, ()=> {
  console.log('server is up');
});
```

----routes----

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   res.send('Test');
})     

module.exports = router;
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? I suspect it's something to do with exporting app but I really don't know how to fix it at this point

Comment: When you launch the server, which files are you launching with?

Comment: Also, you show `const indexRoutes = require('./Routes/index');`, but the only file with routes in it you call `routes`, not `index.js`.  Exporting of the `app` looks fine to me.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am launching the server with server.js could that be the issue?

Comment: Nope, that's right.  See my answer below for the issue with calling `next()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you aren't calling `next()` in your middleware:

So this:

```
//set cors
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET", "POST");
});
```

needs to be changed to this:

```
//set cors
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET", "POST");
   next();
});
```

So, as soon as the request gets to this middleware, no other routing happens as it never passes control back to Express by calling `next()` to check for other routes or middleware that match.

Comment: You got it right! I just fixed that and I am getting the response from the view ! Thank you, you saved my night :)